# Different errors when trying to get a compute engine with gpu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When I try to build a compute engine with gpu, I encounter some errors.

Example1:

- us-east1-c
- 8_vcpu
- 30gb_ram
- 4xTESLA_T4
- Deep Learning Image: PyTorch 1.1.0 and fastai m25 CUDA 10.0 with 30gb
- both firewall choices (http, https) are selected

Error1: Quota 'NVIDIA_T4_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 in region us-east1.

Example2:

- us-east1-c
- 8_vcpu
- 30gb_ram
- 1xTESLA_T4
- Deep Learning Image: PyTorch 1.1.0 and fastai m25 CUDA 10.0 with 30gb
- both firewall choices (http, https) are selected

Error2:  Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally.

Example3:

- us-central1-a
- 8_vcpu
- 30gb_ram
- 2xTESLA_V100
- Deep Learning Image: PyTorch 1.1.0 and fastai m25 CUDA 10.0 with 30gb
- both firewall choices (http, https) are selected

Error3:  Quota 'NVIDIA_V100_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 1.0 in region us-central1.

Example4:

- us-west1-b
- 8_vcpu
- 30gb_ram
- 1xTESLA_V100
- Deep Learning Image: PyTorch 1.1.0 and fastai m25 CUDA 10.0 with 30gb
- both firewall choices (http, https) are selected

Error4:  Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally.

Is there any other way to get a compute engine with gpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize and add documentation to the existing answer and its respective comments:

GPUs are not included in the ‘Always Free’ GCP resources as explained by the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits).

If you’re using the ‘12-month, $300 free trial’, you can find on the 'Program coverage' row of the table pointed by [this link](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) that it is not possible to add GPUs to Compute Engine instances.

In [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/), you can find the GPU models that are available for both compute and graphics workloads as well as the zones in which they’re available.

For their respective pricing you can find information [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#gpus).

For more background on GPU quotas and how to request their increase, refer to [this section](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus) of the Compute Engine documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer, but it leaves one thing unclear. The trial limitation that you are mentioning are lifted immediately as soon as you upgrade to a full account from a trial account. This changes nothing: you still have your free $300 for 12 months. The only distinction, as I understand it, is that you will be billed if you exhaust the promo allotment. So the entirely correct answer should mention that. Personally, I started with GCE explicitly to run GPU loads, and upgraded the account withing a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

Check quotas on `IAM->Quotas`, you can filter the Metric by `GPU`.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this feature. I filtered by T4 and V100, for all of the rows limit is 1. However as you can see in my examples, I selected 1xv100 and get the last error.

Comment: Any chance you are using a free trial? Otherwise, try to request an increase in quota

Comment: Yes I am using a free trial. From where should I ask an increase in quota?

Comment: For free trial account, it's not allowed to create instances with GPU. Upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: If I upgrade to a paid account, can I still use my $300 credit?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that if the credit runs out, you will be charged.

Comment: By paid accounts are you referring to these?: https://imgur.com/w8r9tSX Will silver one be enough to demand quota increase?

Comment: You can find `Upgrade` on GCP console. See https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade